# I have GBs of Event-Based Data. How do I figure out causation?

Tags: regression, optimization, causality, svd, large-data

I have a lot of event-based data about users of our website. For example, data in the format (verb, timestamp). There's about 10 or so different verbs (call them A, B, C, etc).

I'm interested in figuring out different events' contribution to a users' decision to purchase a membership.

i.e.

P(chance to buy in a given month) = A * contribution-of-a + B * contribution-of-b +  ...

This is a tricky problem because some things might happen many times (user makes a friend) and some things might happen rarely (user uploads a level). I'm also trying to establish causation instead of just correlation.

It seems like this problem has a lot of degrees of freedom. Is it even possible in theory to solve? How do other companies optimize this? What is the statistics technique that I should Google for?

Is this what a Singular Value Decomposition is for?

Comment: I don't know how you think that causation can be inferred from observational data.  The best you can hope for is explanation/prediction.  You might re-phrase the question to get better answers.

Comment: @FrankHarrell I think [Judea Pearl](http://bayes.cs.ucla.edu/BOOK-2K/) would beg to differ. You need some stronger assumptions (like that you actually observed all the causally relevant variables), but different causal structures _can_ (and often _do_) place different constraints on the joint distribution (which means you can look at the data and tell them apart). I will say that just throwing the data into a logistic regression or doing SVD will _not_ answer the OP's question.

Comment: In the case of "users of our website", you never observe all causally relevant variables.

Comment: It doesn't matter how fancy the methods are, if they assume that you've measured everything relevant and you can't prove that you did, causal inference is problematic.  A sensitivity analysis can help, e.g., what properties must an unmeasured confounder have before the association would be explained away.

Comment: @FrankHarrell People basically always **do** make causal inferences about data, regardless of whether they are warranted. Giving methodological help on causal analysis (like your very good suggestion about sensitivity analysis) seems more helpful than saying "the best you can hope for" is to throw the data in a regression, recite the incantation "correlation does not imply causation", and then pretend that it does. I know I'm unfairly summarizing your first comment, but I'm pretty sure that's the end result of trying to dissuade someone from asking causal questions about data.

Comment: One interesting thing about "correlation does not imply causation" is that it is also true that "correlation does not not imply causation" - it's always seemed to me that the truth is somewhere in the middle.

Comment: But in this case, I have timestamps on events, which seems like it *should* help on locking down causation. For instance, if in 100 users histories, event C never happens unless preceded by and event B, there is some calculable probability that B -> C?

Comment: The fact that people make mistakes all the time is not an excuse.  So I could not disagree more with Joe Pete.

Comment: @FrankHarrell If the question was phrased _"We will modify our website to increase sales, based on conclusions from this data. What should we do?"_ would you still think _"don't ask causal questions"_ is the best advice?

Comment: That's an excellent question.  An analogy: epidemiologic studies found that cholesterol was a risk factor for cardiovascular disease.  This significant association formed the basis for intervention studies that showed you can modify risk by lowering cholesterol. Showing an association made it worthwhile to proceed, while not proving that lowering cholesterol would change individuals' risks.  I think we base decisions on associations quite often.  But a paper from the business literature (lost the reference) showed randomized experiments could be done more often, including web services (Yahoo).

Answer (score 3):

That's not what SVD is for.  However it does look like a reasonable application for a logistic regression model though, perhaps with a rate events correction if people don't often buy things.

Before launching into that you might want to think about how the verbs could relate to purchase decisions.  Three basic questions might be: a) do A, B, C, etc. have independent effects on purchasing probability or might they operate together?  If they do, this suggests an additive specification.  b) Is it the case that more (or less) of each verb matters, or is it more of one verb than another?  If the latter, this affects how you code your users' behaviour, e.g. in ratios, counts, proportions etc. c) Do they purchase different things and does this matter? This may affect whether it is more helpful to model buying something, or buying Y rather than Z, and consequently what the dependent variable(s) might be.

Any statistical package will fit such a model for you. The key is knowing what it's telling you when it's finished, and here more importantly whether it fits well enough to be trusted for prediction: On this latter question, consider what you might *do* with a positive prediction, and thus how much it might cost to do that thing.  ROC curves are useful here.

To the causal question. Some of the commenters claim that you won't necessarily get causal information from this model fitting exercise.  That's correct.  However you can run experiments within your website to see if randomly selected users will change their purchasing behaviour.  You might even stratify by verb combination if you get the idea that some people are more susceptible than others to the manipulation.  That's really the final test of whether some regularity thrown up in the fitted model actually corresponds to a cause of purchasing behaviour rather than simply a correlate.

Comment: A big +1 for A/B tests on your users

Comment: I think even assuming the form of the solution is dicey. In reality, the contribution of every event to a purchase decision is related by some function to every other event.

Comment: @JohnShedletsky that's ok. If you've really got gigabytes of data to work with you can probably fit a pretty darn complicated model. In any case unfortunately you don't get to 'not assume' the form of the solution. Any model you choose assumes some form or other, even the SVD, and even so-called 'non-parametric' ones.  But if your aim is to predict well and maybe experiment later, then being misspecified might not matter at all.